# libxerces-c.so: undefined reference to many packages

Tags: c++, installation, ocr

I am getting the below error while running the steps (in make for seshat) I don't know why this is coming the seshat is written in c++ and I have never installed something in C++ kindly help how should I install this on my system(centos 7).
If the question you find very naive then kindly help I know it might be as I am very new to cpp things.
I am following this [link](https://github.com/falvaro/seshat) for installing seshat
[image]

My make file looks like this:

```
CC=g++
LINK=-lxerces-c -lm
FLAGS = -O3 -Wno-unused-result #-I/path/to/boost/

OBJFEAS=symfeatures.o featureson.o online.o
OBJMUESTRA=sample.o stroke.o
OBJPARSE=seshat.o meparser.o gparser.o grammar.o production.o symrec.o 
duration.o segmentation.o sparel.o gmm.o
OBJTABLA=tablecyk.o cellcyk.o hypothesis.o logspace.o
OBJRNNLIB=Random.o DataExporter.o WeightContainer.o ClassificationLayer.o 
Layer.o Mdrnn.o Optimiser.o
RNNLIBHEADERS=rnnlib4seshat/DataSequence.hpp rnnlib4seshat/NetcdfDataset.hpp 
rnnlib4seshat/Mdrnn.hpp rnnlib4seshat/MultilayerNet.hpp rnnlib4seshat/Rprop.hpp 
rnnlib4seshat/SteepestDescent.hpp rnnlib4seshat/Trainer.hpp 
rnnlib4seshat/WeightContainer.hpp
OBJS=$(OBJFEAS) $(OBJMUESTRA) $(OBJPARSE) $(OBJTABLA) $(OBJRNNLIB)

seshat: $(OBJS)
    $(CC) -o seshat $(OBJS) $(FLAGS) $(LINK)

seshat.o: seshat.cc grammar.o sample.o meparser.o
    $(CC) -c seshat.cc $(FLAGS)

production.o: production.h production.cc symrec.o
    $(CC) -c production.cc $(FLAGS)

grammar.o: grammar.h grammar.cc production.o gparser.o symrec.o
    $(CC) -c grammar.cc $(FLAGS)

meparser.o: meparser.h meparser.cc grammar.o production.o symrec.o tablecyk.o 
cellcyk.o logspace.o duration.o segmentation.o sparel.o sample.o hypothesis.o
    $(CC) -c meparser.cc $(FLAGS)

gparser.o: gparser.h gparser.cc
    $(CC) -c gparser.cc $(FLAGS)

sample.o: sample.h sample.cc tablecyk.o cellcyk.o stroke.o grammar.o
    $(CC) -c sample.cc $(FLAGS)

symrec.o: symrec.h symrec.cc symfeatures.o $(RNNLIBHEADERS)
    $(CC) -c symrec.cc $(FLAGS)

duration.o: duration.h duration.cc symrec.o
    $(CC) -c duration.cc $(FLAGS)

segmentation.o: segmentation.h segmentation.cc cellcyk.o sample.o gmm.o
    $(CC) -c segmentation.cc $(FLAGS)

tablecyk.o: tablecyk.h tablecyk.cc cellcyk.o hypothesis.o
    $(CC) -c tablecyk.cc $(FLAGS)

cellcyk.o: cellcyk.h cellcyk.cc hypothesis.o
    $(CC) -c cellcyk.cc $(FLAGS)

hypothesis.o: hypothesis.h hypothesis.cc production.o grammar.o
    $(CC) -c hypothesis.cc $(FLAGS)

logspace.o: logspace.h logspace.cc cellcyk.o
    $(CC) -c logspace.cc $(FLAGS)

sparel.o: sparel.h sparel.cc hypothesis.o cellcyk.o gmm.o sample.o
    $(CC) -c sparel.cc $(FLAGS)

gmm.o: gmm.cc gmm.h
    $(CC) -c gmm.cc $(FLAGS)

stroke.o: stroke.cc stroke.h
    $(CC) -c stroke.cc $(FLAGS)

symfeatures.o: symfeatures.cc online.o featureson.o
    $(CC) -c symfeatures.cc $(FLAGS)

featureson.o: featureson.cc featureson.h online.o
    $(CC) -c featureson.cc $(FLAGS)

online.o: online.cc online.h
    $(CC) -c online.cc $(FLAGS)

#rnnlib4seshat
Random.o: rnnlib4seshat/Random.cpp
    $(CC) -c rnnlib4seshat/Random.cpp $(FLAGS)

DataExporter.o: rnnlib4seshat/DataExporter.cpp
    $(CC) -c rnnlib4seshat/DataExporter.cpp $(FLAGS)

WeightContainer.o: rnnlib4seshat/WeightContainer.cpp
    $(CC) -c rnnlib4seshat/WeightContainer.cpp $(FLAGS)

ClassificationLayer.o: rnnlib4seshat/ClassificationLayer.cpp
    $(CC) -c rnnlib4seshat/ClassificationLayer.cpp $(FLAGS)

Layer.o: rnnlib4seshat/Layer.cpp
    $(CC) -c rnnlib4seshat/Layer.cpp $(FLAGS)

Mdrnn.o: rnnlib4seshat/Mdrnn.cpp
    $(CC) -c rnnlib4seshat/Mdrnn.cpp $(FLAGS)

Optimiser.o: rnnlib4seshat/Optimiser.cpp
    $(CC) -c rnnlib4seshat/Optimiser.cpp $(FLAGS)

clean:
    rm -f *.o *~ \#*\#
```

Comment: It seems you have installed the Xerces library yourself, possibly from source. Have you read the documentation for that library? Especially any sections about prerequisite requirements? Like perhaps the ICU library? Perhaps you should spend a little time reading the documentation about CentOS as well, to learn how to install packages (if ICU is in the repository)? And haven't you tried to install Xerces from the CentOS repositories? Then any dependency should have been installed automatically.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Someprogrammerdude for replying!! Yes I have spend time on that 1. I installed it using YUM 2. I installed it from source. Can you tell me any good online content I could follow to install Xerces properly I will be very grateful!!

Comment: Another Question is how can tell this make (of seshat to use xerces to pick up from different location which is in usr/lib64, which I installed using YUM)

Comment: I installed xerces from YUM using this https://centos.pkgs.org/7/centos-x86_64/xerces-c-3.1.1-9.el7.x86_64.rpm.html

Comment: Have you tried to install `libicu-devel`? From the error messages, it seems that the library is missing.

Comment: @Gilles-PhilippePaillé I have installed this still giving the same error